# What is meant by static invocation in definition of call_user_func

Tags: php, callback

I have problems to understand the PHP manual for [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call_user_func), especially the parameter description:

> The function to be called. Class methods may also be ***invoked statically*** using this function by passing `array($classname, $methodname)` to this parameter.

Example: Using a class method

```
<?php
class myclass {
   function say_hello()
   {
       echo "Hello!\n";
   }
}

$classname = "myclass";

call_user_func(array($classname, 'say_hello'));
?>
```

Also kindly explain this code line "call_user_func(array($classname, 'say_hello'))". Of course `array($classname, 'say_hello')` is not a method name.

Comment: Can you please share the link of the manual page you quoted that text from?

Answer (score 1):

Passing an array to `call_user_func` is a special case for invoking class methods, static and non-static. In the example you gave, you could do this:

```
<?php
class myclass {
   public function say_hello()
   {
       echo "Hello!\n";
   }

   public static function say_hello_static() {
       echo "Hello static!\n";
   }
}

//Call static method
call_user_func(array('myclass','say_hello_static'));

//Call object method
$myobject = new myclass();
call_user_func(array($myobject,'say_hello'));
?>
```

As of PHP 5.2.3 you can call static methods by using a string, instead of an array, e.g:

```
call_user_func('myclass::say_hello_static');
```